# firebase observer snapshot partial data

Tags: swift, firebase, observers

I have a list of items and an observer that suppose to update that list when an item is being added (with an observer (childAdded))

[screenShot of my DB + Snapshot in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHwDz.png)

when this item is created at the ref in firebase I can see all of it in the DB.

(here in my screenshot the -KDSPrkNZVGbhrg2JOEe item is existing and Im adding the KDTIER7vD4J2C_Y350V item)

but in the snapshot(left side of my screenshot) that I get from the observer all the participant node object doesnt appear its like Im getting from the snapshot only the first level of childs

what am I doing wrong??? Is There a possibility that the observer make the snapshot before all the data being created in the DB?

here my JSON file

```
{
  "d4db8fd9-7d90-4125-860f-eafd38f53926" : {
    "-KDSMZ3_puh_KezRwzVx" : {
      "name" : "test 1",
      "numOfParticipants" : 4,
      "participants" : {
        "0525515345" : {
          "lastName" : "Korach",
          "name" : "Yonathan",
          "phoneNumber" : "0525515345"
        },
        "0542824847" : {
          "lastName" : "Ben Attar",
          "name" : "Ofer",
          "phoneNumber" : "0542824847"
        },
        "0587006381" : {
          "lastName" : "Brami",
          "name" : "Auriel",
          "phoneNumber" : "0587006381"
        }
      },
      "photo" : "",
      "place" : "Meatos",
      "time" : "2016-03-23 08:00:20 +0000"
    },
    "-KDSPrkNZVGbhrg2JOEe" : {
      "name" : "test 2",
      "numOfParticipants" : 2,
      "participants" : {
        "0525515345" : {
          "lastName" : "Korach",
          "name" : "Yonathan",
          "phoneNumber" : "0525515345"
        }
      },
      "photo" : "",
      "place" : "Dizzy Bar",
      "time" : "2016-03-24 08:15:54 +0000"
    },
    "-KDTIER7vD4J2C_Y350V » : {
      "name" : "test3",
      "numOfParticipants" : 2,
      "participants" : {
        "0587006381" : {
          "lastName" : "Brami",
          "name" : "Auriel",
          "phoneNumber" : "0587006381"
        }
      },
      "photo" : "",
      "place" : "Agadir Burger",
      "time" : "2016-03-25 12:00:16 +0000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thanks. Now also add the textual version of your code. Then clean up your text to fit around the JSON and code and it'll be in a lot better shape.